# Count Boolean Variable By Date

Tags: python, pandas

I've been posting a lot lately as I'm new to Python/Pandas. I have a pandas DF called NOTES_TAT_v1. It looks like this:

```
PT_FIN    Date                Interpreter Needed    Interpreter Used
1        27 January, 2020         1                        1
2        27 January, 2020         1                        0
3        27 January, 2020         0                        0
4        28 January, 2020         0                        0
5        28 January, 2020         1                        1
6        29 January, 2020         1                        0
```

I'm trying to aggregate the Interpreter columns by Date so the output would look like this:

```
Date                Interpreter Needed    Interpreter Used
 27 January, 2020         2                        1
 28 January, 2020         1                        1
 29 January, 2020         2                        1
```

I tried using this code just for the `Interpreter Needed` column (I ultimately want both Interpreter columns): `NOTES_TAT_v2=NOTES_TAT_v1.groupby('Day').Interpreter_Needed.value_counts()`. But I'm getting errors `Traceback (most recent call last)` & `DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Interpreter_Needed'`. Do I need to do a crosstab?

Comment: NOTES_TAT_v1.groupby('Day').sum()?

Comment: you should convert your `Date` to datetime too `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%d %B, %Y')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('df.txt', sep=r"[ ]{2,}")

print(df)

PT_FIN  Date    Interpreter Needed  Interpreter Used
0   1   27 January, 2020    1   1
1   2   27 January, 2020    1   0
2   3   27 January, 2020    0   0
3   4   28 January, 2020    0   0
4   5   28 January, 2020    1   1
5   6   29 January, 2020    1   0

df_gb = df[['Interpreter Needed', 'Interpreter Used']].groupby([df['Date']])

print(df_gb.sum())

        Interpreter Needed  Interpreter Used
Date        
27 January, 2020    2   1
28 January, 2020    1   1
29 January, 2020    1   0
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked beautifully, how would I export the printed table to an excel document - I already have my OS code and pathway...os.chdir('Q:\Data Notes\Python\Sample Output')   with pd.ExcelWriter("Interpreter Data.xlsx") as writer: 
  NOTES_TAT.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Interpreter')

Comment: Just do df_gb.sum().to_excel("your file path here.xlsx"). You can add arguments as needed. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html